# AWS DMS Migration from AWS Aurora PostgreSQL to AZURE PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, migration, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database on AWS Aurora to Azure. I have already set the demo, however, when I try to run the migration it fails. CloudWatch doesn't send anything relevant:

[image: CloudWatch]

Last failure message is `Internal failure`. And Fail message is:

> Data migration failed
> The prerequisites for DMS to use the source database have not been met. Configure the user account permissions or privileges for DMS and restart the migration.

Something important is that when I created the migration project I used the Aurora instance as a Postgres instance, otherwise it wouldn't work.

When I run the migration sometimes it actually complete the full load, however it sends an error and it says that no data was loaded.

If you need more info I can provide.

Thank you.

I have tried following [Prerequisites to using a self-managed PostgreSQL database as a AWS DMS source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Prerequisites.SelfManaged) but I doesn't seem to work.